# Moving average of previous three values in R

Tags: r, zoo, moving-average

In the zoo package there is a function called rollmean, which enables you to make moving averages. The `rollmean(x,3)` will take the previous, current and next value (ie 4, 6 and 2) in the table below. This is shown in the second column.

```
x   rollmean    ma3
4       
6   4.0 
2   4.3 
5   3.0         4.0
2   6.3         4.3
12  6.0         3.0
4   6.0         6.3
2               6.0
```

I would like to get the same job done, but by averaging out the previous 3 values in the fourth row. This is displayed in the third column. Can anybody tell me the name of the function that will help to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use `filter(x,rep(1/3,3),sides=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simplier implementation of w_i_l_l's mavback function based on his mav function

`mavback <- function(x,n){ filter(x, c(0, rep(1/n,n)), sides=1) }`

Comment: If you're using dplyr, make sure to make the call to filter explicit stats::filter

Answer (score 23):

You can use `rollmean`, but set `align='right'`.  Or you could use `rollmeanr`, which has `align='right'` as the default.

```
ma3 <- rollmeanr(x[,1],3,fill=NA)
```

...but you would still need to lag the result.  Another solution is to use `rollapply` with a list for the `width` argument:

```
ma3 <- rollapplyr(x[,1],list(-(3:1)),mean,fill=NA)
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "...but you would still need to lag the result"? thanks

Comment: They wanted the previous 3 values in the 4th row. Each observation in `ma3` contains the mean of the current row and the previous 2 rows. So The 4th row of `ma3` contains the mean of rows 2, 3, 4; not 1, 2, 3, like they wanted.

Answer (score 12):

I struggled searching for a simple function for moving averages that had some flexibility to do what I needed.  I finally wrote a couple functions extending the one based on the filter function which rinni gives above in the comment (but which itself won't work because it will include the current observation in the 3 period average).

1. Moving average function that includes the current observation

   ```
   mav <- function(x,n){filter(x,rep(1/n,n), sides=1)}
   ```
2. Moving average function that does not include the current observation

   ```
   mavback <- function(x,n){
     a<-mav(x,1)
     b<-mav(x,(n+1))
     c<-(1/n)*((n+1)*b - a)
     return(c)
   }
   ```
3. Backward looking moving average function, not including current obs, based on [h2] readings starting [h1] periods back

   ```
   mavback1<-function(x,h1,h2){
     a<-mavback(x,h1)
     b<-mavback(x,h1-h2)
     c<-(1/h2)*(h1*a -(h1-h2)*b)
     return(c)
   }
   ```