# R, calculating last 3 average

Tags: r, function, moving-average

I have the following data frame in R. It contains the statistics of each player in the Olympics basketball tournament
Sample Table

[image]

Each game is denoted by a number in the game column. I would like to create a new column with the average of the last 3 games. When following examples in similar posts, my biggest down fall is having games numbers instead of actual dates that seem to be required for other methods.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT: 
To clarify a little more based on some of the solutions and suggestions. For each row I would like to have the new column show the Average minutes or points from the last 3 games. So far the suggestion make each row show the average of games 3, 4, & 5.

So for example. 
Player A, game = 3 
Avg Pts = mean(pts game1, pts game2, pts game3)

Player B, game = 4
Avg pts = mean(pts game2 ,pts game3, pts game4)

I hope that clears it up.
Thanks

Data:

I am very new at this. I hope this is the appropriate method for sharing data.

```
structure(list(Player = structure(c(1L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 17L, 21L, 
23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 12L, 15L, 11L, 
5L, 15L, 16L, 14L, 9L, 20L, 11L, 18L, 4L, 12L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 20L, 
12L, 5L, 13L, 22L, 7L, 11L, 20L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 19L, 
3L, 7L, 14L, 5L), .Label = c("Adas Juskevicius", "Alex Abrines", 
"Andrew Bogut", "Bojan Bogdanovic", "Boris Diaw", "Brock Motum", 
"Dario Saric", "Dwight Lewis", "Facundo Campazzo", "Ike Diogu", 
"Jianlian Yi", "Jonas Maciulis", "Kevin Durant", "Luis Scola", 
"Mantas Kalnietis", "Matt Dellavedova", "Miguel Marriaga", "Milos Teodosic", 
"Nikola Mirotic", "Pau Gasol", "Rafa Luz", "Ricky Rubio", "Roberto Acuna", 
"Vaidas Kariniauskas", "Windi Graterol", "Zeljko Sakic"), class = "factor"), 
    Team = structure(c(8L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 12L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 6L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 
    5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("ARG", 
    "AUS", "BRZ", "CHN", "CRO", "ESP", "FRA", "LTU", "NGR", "SRB", 
    "USA", "VEN"), class = "factor"), Pos = structure(c(3L, 4L, 
    2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("C", "PF", "PG", "SF", "SG"), class = "factor"), 
    game = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Status = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), Drafted = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 85, 
    82, 80, 78, 77, 74, 68, 68, 68, 65, 64, 63, 62, 62, 61, 61, 
    60, 59, 59, 59, 58, 57, 57, 57, 56, 56, 56, 55, 55, 55, 55, 
    54, 54, 53, 53, 52, 51), Min = c(11.04, 1.44, 16.56, 2.88, 
    4.8, 1.92, 13.68, 3.84, 9.36, 2.64, 21.12, 17.04, 0.24, 36.48, 
    32.16, 23.28, 26.88, 17.28, 33.6, 28.56, 30.48, 19.92, 30.24, 
    25.92, 27.84, 34.8, 15.12, 36, 28.8, 29.04, 29.28, 21.36, 
    23.04, 18.72, 21.12, 25.2, 12.24, 27.12, 32.88, 31.92, 34.08, 
    18.24, 27.6, 32.64, 33.6, 32.88, 24.72, 34.8, 35.76, 31.44
    ), FIC = c(3.8, 1.5, 10.2, 1, 0, -1, 0.2, 0.5, -3.2, -1, 
    0.6, 4.5, -0.5, 15.6, 9.5, 11.1, 0.5, 7.8, 17, 16.8, 25.2, 
    10.5, 10, 6, 14.4, 6, 7.5, 15.5, 14.8, 6.2, 7.9, 3, 26.9, 
    0.8, 11.4, 16, -1, 4.9, 14.1, 18.5, 5.9, 6.5, 10, 10, 10, 
    8, 19, 9, 12.1, 7.5), FP = c(8, 4, 21.75, 2, 2.75, -0.5, 
    4.75, 1.5, 2.5, 1.25, 8.5, 13, 0, 35.25, 37, 32.25, 17, 18.5, 
    39.5, 34.25, 49, 19.25, 28.75, 20.25, 41.25, 27.5, 16.5, 
    39.25, 33.5, 29, 30.75, 13.25, 47.25, 9, 24.5, 28.5, 6.25, 
    19.5, 38.25, 40.25, 27.5, 17, 21.75, 37.5, 29, 21, 38.5, 
    30.75, 37.75, 25.75), FPM = c(0.72463768115942, 2.77777777777778, 
    1.31340579710145, 0.694444444444444, 0.572916666666667, -0.260416666666667, 
    0.347222222222222, 0.390625, 0.267094017094017, 0.473484848484848, 
    0.402462121212121, 0.762910798122066, 0, 0.966282894736842, 
    1.15049751243781, 1.38530927835052, 0.632440476190476, 1.07060185185185, 
    1.17559523809524, 1.19922969187675, 1.60761154855643, 0.96636546184739, 
    0.950727513227513, 0.78125, 1.48168103448276, 0.790229885057471, 
    1.09126984126984, 1.09027777777778, 1.16319444444444, 0.99862258953168, 
    1.05020491803279, 0.620318352059925, 2.05078125, 0.480769230769231, 
    1.16003787878788, 1.13095238095238, 0.51062091503268, 0.719026548672566, 
    1.16332116788321, 1.2609649122807, 0.806924882629108, 0.932017543859649, 
    0.78804347826087, 1.14889705882353, 0.863095238095238, 0.638686131386861, 
    1.55744336569579, 0.883620689655172, 1.05564876957494, 0.819020356234097
    ), PTS = c(5L, 2L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 9L, 
    0L, 17L, 13L, 16L, 10L, 16L, 18L, 11L, 21L, 6L, 12L, 10L, 
    19L, 20L, 7L, 28L, 21L, 10L, 18L, 10L, 23L, 4L, 7L, 16L, 
    0L, 7L, 20L, 26L, 22L, 10L, 7L, 19L, 14L, 6L, 9L, 15L, 23L, 
    9L), TPM = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), Ast = c(2L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 9L, 12L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 
    5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
    3L, 0L, 2L), Reb = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 0L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 
    3L, 13L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    6L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 7L, 9L, 5L), BLK = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), STL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L), TO = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    6L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 
    2L, 6L, 4L, 2L)), .Names = c("Player", "Team", "Pos", "game", 
"Status", "Drafted", "Min", "FIC", "FP", "FPM", "PTS", "TPM", 
"Ast", "Reb", "BLK", "STL", "TO"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried `zoo::rollmean(mtcars$mpg, k=3)`? If not, please provide sample data (using `dput` or similar) and sample code tried. A good reference for "making it easy for us to help you" can be found at [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added more data (50 rows) and clarified the question

Comment: So for Player A, game = **4** Avg Pts = mean(pts game2, pts game3, pts game4) ? Could you add how the output would look like for player `Vaidas Kariniauskas`, he has 4 games, 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rollmeanr` from the `zoo` package with `dplyr`. This has the feature that not only the last three games of a player is averaged, but the last three game moving average is computed for each player. The code is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

avg.last.3 <- function (x) if (length(x) < 3) rep(NA, length(x)) else rollmeanr(x, 3, fill = NA)  ## 1.

res <- df %>% group_by(Player) %>% arrange(game) %>%     ## 2.
              mutate(Avg.Pts=avg.last.3(PTS)) %>%        ## 3.
              ungroup() %>% arrange(Player,game)         ## 4.
```

Notes:

1. Define a function `avg.last.3` that applies the function `rollmeanr` with window length of `3`. `rollmeanr` specifies `align="right"` to average the *last* three games, and we pad any result that does not have three days to average by `NA`. Note that the `if` condition in this function is needed so that:

   - length of `x` is at least the window length for `rollmeanr` as required by `rollmeanr`
   - `avg.last.3` returns a vector that is the same length as its input as required by `mutate`.
2. First `group_by` the `Player`. Since I noted that the `game` column is not necessarily sorted for each `Player`, we sort by `game` in ascending order.
3. Use `mutate` to create a new column `Avg.Pts` resulting from applying the `avg.last.3` function on a column, for example `PTS`.
4. Finally, `ungroup` and present the result sorted by `Player` followed by `game`

Of course, you can get the average of any number of columns by:

```
mutate(Avg.Pts=avg.last.3(PTS), Avg.Min=avg.last.3(Min), Avg.Ast=avg.last.3(Ast), ...)
```

The results averaging only the `PTS` column is given by (printing only the first six columns plus `PTS` and `Avg.Pts`):

```
print(res[,c(colnames(res)[1:6],"PTS","Avg.Pts")],n=50)
### A tibble: 50 x 8
##                Player   Team    Pos  game Status Drafted   PTS   Avg.Pts
##                <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <int>  <int>   <dbl> <int>     <dbl>
##1     Adas Juskevicius    LTU     PG     4      0       0     5        NA
##2         Alex Abrines    ESP     SF     5      0       0     2        NA
##3         Andrew Bogut    AUS      C     2      1      53     9        NA
##4     Bojan Bogdanovic    CRO     PF     2      1      59    18        NA
##5     Bojan Bogdanovic    CRO     PF     4      1      61    28        NA
##6     Bojan Bogdanovic    CRO     PF     5      1      55    22 22.666667
##7           Boris Diaw    FRA     PF     1      1      51     9        NA
##8           Boris Diaw    FRA     PF     2      1      57     7        NA
##9           Boris Diaw    FRA     PF     3      1      68    11  9.000000
##10          Boris Diaw    FRA     PF     4      1      55    10  9.333333
##11         Brock Motum    AUS     PF     4      0       0    15        NA
##12         Dario Saric    CRO     SF     3      1      53    15        NA
##13         Dario Saric    CRO     SF     4      1      56     7        NA
##14        Dwight Lewis    VEN     SG     5      0       0     0        NA
##15    Facundo Campazzo    ARG     PG     2      1      60    10        NA
##16    Facundo Campazzo    ARG     PG     3      1      64    10        NA
##17    Facundo Campazzo    ARG     PG     5      0      59    10 10.000000
##18           Ike Diogu    NGR     PF     3      1      55     7        NA
##19         Jianlian Yi    CHN     SF     2      1      55    19        NA
##20         Jianlian Yi    CHN     PF     3      1      74    18        NA
##21         Jianlian Yi    CHN     SF     4      1      56    20 19.000000
##22         Jianlian Yi    CHN     SF     5      1      62    20 19.333333
##23      Jonas Maciulis    LTU     PF     2      1      61    21        NA
##24      Jonas Maciulis    LTU     SF     3      1      78    10        NA
##25      Jonas Maciulis    LTU     PF     4      1      58     4 11.666667
##26        Kevin Durant    USA     SF     2      1      57    16        NA
##27          Luis Scola    ARG      C     2      1      52    23        NA
##28          Luis Scola    ARG     PF     3      1      65    12        NA
##29          Luis Scola    ARG      C     4      1      54    14 16.333333
##30    Mantas Kalnietis    LTU     SG     2      1      68    21        NA
##31    Mantas Kalnietis    LTU     PG     3      1      85    17        NA
##32    Mantas Kalnietis    LTU     SG     4      1      77    16 18.000000
##33    Matt Dellavedova    AUS     PG     4      1      68     6        NA
##34     Miguel Marriaga    VEN     PF     3      0       0     0        NA
##35      Milos Teodosic    SRB     SG     5      0      62     7        NA
##36      Nikola Mirotic    ESP     PF     2      1      54     6        NA
##37           Pau Gasol    ESP      C     1      1      56    26        NA
##38           Pau Gasol    ESP      C     2      1      82    13        NA
##39           Pau Gasol    ESP      C     3      1      80    16 18.333333
##40           Pau Gasol    ESP      C     4      1      59    23 17.333333
##41           Pau Gasol    ESP      C     5      1      63    19 19.333333
##42            Rafa Luz    BRZ     SG     4      0       0     0        NA
##43         Ricky Rubio    ESP     PG     1      1      57     0        NA
##44       Roberto Acuna    ARG      C     3      1       0     2        NA
##45 Vaidas Kariniauskas    LTU     PF     1      0       0     0        NA
##46 Vaidas Kariniauskas    LTU     PF     2      0       0     0        NA
##47 Vaidas Kariniauskas    LTU     PF     3      0       0     0  0.000000
##48 Vaidas Kariniauskas    LTU     PF     4      0       0     6  2.000000
##49      Windi Graterol    VEN      C     5      0       0     9        NA
##50        Zeljko Sakic    CRO     SF     5      0       0     0        NA
```

Comment: I have one more question about this solution. I noticed the last 3 average included the current game in the result. Is it possible to modify the function to get the last 3 average of the previous 3 games?

So for game number 4, the Last 3 average would be average of game 1,2, & 3.

thanks

Comment: @sangacollins: Courtesy of [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193333/moving-average-of-previous-three-values-in-r), define `avg.prev.3 <- function (x) if (length(x) < 4) rep(NA,length(x)) else rollapplyr(x,list(-(3:1)),mean,fill=NA)` and use it instead.

Comment: Thanks! that did it. I now have a good handle of how it works and found another method which helps when there is gaps in data i used it for last 3 game minute average


   `res <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(Player) %>% arrange(date) %>% 
                          mutate(min1 = lag(Min, 1, default = NA)) %>% 
                          mutate(min3 = rollapply(min1,width=3,mean,align= "right",    fill=NA, partial=TRUE)))`

Answer (score 5):

Using dplyr with mtcars example data:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(last3mean = mean(tail(mpg, 3)))
```

In your case, instead of **cyl** and **mpg**, use **Player** and the column to aggregate.

Using data.table, (suggested by @akrun):

```
data.table as.data.table(mtcar‌​s)[, .(last3mean = mean(tail(mpg,3))), by = cyl]
```

Comment: I like your suggestion. It is closely aligned with I have learned so far in my last couple of weeks using R. I figured Split/apply/combine would be the way to go, but just needed to wrap my head around the method. If I wanted to show the avg of the last 3 based on the number in the "game" column, where would I need to take the code? right now it appears to be the same result for all players

Comment: Player   Team    Pos  game Status Drafted   Min   FIC    FP        FPM   PTS   TPM   Ast   Reb   BLK   STL    TO last3mean
1     Adas Juskevicius    LTU     PG     4      0       0 11.04   3.8  8.00  0.7246377     5     1     2     0     0     0     1      9.44
2         Alex Abrines    ESP     SF     5      0       0  1.44   1.5  4.00  2.7777778     2     0     0     0     1     0     0      9.44
3          Brock Motum    AUS     PF     4      0       0 16.56  10.2 21.75  1.3134058    15     0     2     3     0     0     0      9.44

Answer (score 0):

First split the data frame up by player

```
playerDFs <- split(origdata, origdata["Player"])
```

Then subset the last 3 games

```
playerLast3 <- lapply(playerDFs, function(x) x[tail(order(x[["game"]]),3), ])
```

Finally get your means

```
vapply(playerLast3, colMeans, numeric(ncol(origdata)))
```

Comment: Hi Barker, I ran into an "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'x' must be numeric" but I am pretty sure I can fix that. Your solution provided the Average of the last 3 games for player in game number 5. What I would like to do is have each player row show the average of the last 3 games they played in. So player row game 4 would have the average of 1, 2 & 3. I am going to try and make this into a for loop to hopefully get the result